# Expand side area based on the content of the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying expand one area based on the height of the other with jQuery. However, the first area has dynamic content, so I can't set a fixed value as I did in JS code (line 6, with 175px of height).

I have an example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyEZjv.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="columns row-8">
        <section id="summary" class="area">
            <main>
                <div id="details">
                    <div>bla bla</div>
                    <div>bla bla</div>
                    <div>bla bla</div>
                </div>
                <div id="more-details" class="hide">
                    <div>more bla bla</div>
                    <div>more bla bla</div>
                    <div>more bla bla</div>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <button id="more-details-link">View more details</button>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="columns row-4">
        <section id="activity" class="area">
            <main>
                <ul>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                    <li>activity</li>
                </ul>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <a id="full-activity" href="#">See full activity</a>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var minHeight = $('#summary > main').height();
$('#activity > main').height(minHeight);

$('#more-details-link').on('click', function(){
    if ($('#more-details').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#more-details').slideDown();
        // I don't want to set a fixed value, because the first area content may vary
        $('#activity > main').animate({height: '115px'});
    } else {
        $('#more-details').slideUp();
        $('#activity > main').animate({height: minHeight});
    }
});
```

So, the first area has two divs: one is always shown and the other one is hidden by default. When I click the expand button, this area will slide down to show the hidden div. I want the second area to expand as well, using the same slide effect, and **keep the same height of the first area**.
The only way I achieved it was sliding the second area after the first one, not along.

Thanks in advance.

(edit) To be more specific, I want the second area to be the same height as the first one. So, I if the first area is 100px height while collapsed, the second one will have 100px height too. If I expand the first area to 500px, the second one must have the same 500px.

I don't want to set a fixed height to the second area, like I did in the js code. I need to get the first area height and set the same value to the second one. I can't get the height of the first one right after the `slideDown()` because it's an async function and I'll get the wrong height.

PS: I'm limited to jQuery and CSS to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to expand both sections simultaneously, you need to know the height the largest one occupies when expanded.

To make this happen, I use below probably the ugliest trick out there:

```
/* Show and hide '#more-details' instantly to find out the height it reaches. */
var maxHeight;
$('#more-details').show();
maxHeight = $('#summary > main').height();
$('#more-details').hide();
```

When you get this done, you now only have to substitute `'115px'` in your event listener with `maxHeight`:

```
$('#more-details').slideDown();
$('#activity> main').animate({height: maxHeight});
```

Check out the following snippet for more.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */

var
  /* Cache summary, activity and more-details. */
  summary = $('#summary > main'),
  activity = $('#activity > main'),
  moreDetails = $('#more-details'),
  
  /* Cache the height of the summary. */
  minHeight = summary.height(),
  maxHeight;

/* Set the activity to match the summary's height. */
activity.height(minHeight);

/* Show and hide '#more-details' instantly to find out the height it reaches. */
moreDetails.show();
maxHeight = summary.height();
moreDetails.hide();

/* Set the 'click' event of the link. */
$('#more-details-link').on('click', function(){
  if (moreDetails.is(':hidden')) {
    moreDetails.slideDown();
    activity.animate({height: maxHeight});
  } else {
    moreDetails.slideUp();
    activity.animate({height: minHeight});
  }
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
main {padding: 7px}
footer {border-top: 1px solid #000}
.columns {float: left;margin: 10px}
.row-8 {width: 200px}
.row-4 {width: 200px}
.area {background-color: #AAA}
.hide {display: none}
#activity>main {overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="columns row-8">
    <section id="summary" class="area">
      <main>
        <div id="details">
          <div>bla bla</div>
          <div>bla bla</div>
          <div>bla bla</div>
        </div>
        <div id="more-details" class="hide">
          <div>more bla bla</div>
          <div>more bla bla</div>
          <div>more bla bla</div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <button id="more-details-link">View more details</button>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="columns row-4">
    <section id="activity" class="area">
      <main>
        <ul>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
          <li>activity</li>
        </ul>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <a id="full-activity" href="#">See full activity</a>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried this first, but sometimes I can see the area blinking because of other js on the same page. However, I'll accept your answer, since it solves the main problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @GlauberBatista. Which area do you mean? The right or left one?

Comment: The right one. Because it shows all the items and then it has its height adjusted. Also, I managed to make it work with css flex: https://codepen.io/glauberrbatista/pen/LegwXM

Comment: As long as you can use flexbox _(it's actually quite supported now)_ this is the way to go. It's much simpler and without using too much `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question well

If you want to expand the two sections at the same time, what about a multiple selector

```
$('#full-activity, #activity > main')
```

in

```
$('#more-details-link').on('click', function(){
...
  $('#full-activity, #activity > main').animate({height: '115px'});
...
  $('#full-activity, #activity > main').animate({height: minHeight});
```